# af:image is not refreshing

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, oracle-adf

I am posting this Question after alot of Googling and alot of experiments with the af:image component .

my case is the following :

i have an af:link that is opening a af:popup from the backing bean like the following  :

```
<af:link text="Link" id="l3" 
           actionListener="#{myBean.myActionListener}">
    <f:attribute name="personId" value="#{row.PersonId}"/>
    <f:attribute name="fullName" value="#{row.FullName}"/>
  </af:link>
```

and myActionListener method is  like the  following  :

```
public void myActionListener(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

    if (actionEvent.getComponent().getAttributes().get("personId") != null) {

        Long personId = (Long) actionEvent.getComponent().getAttributes().get("personId");
        String fullName = (String)actionEvent.getComponent().getAttributes().get("fullName");


        // puting the attributes in the page Flow Scope 
        AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getPageFlowScope().put("currentPersonId", currentPersonId);
        AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getPageFlowScope().put("currentFullName", currentFullName);

        String imageUrl = "/myImageServlet?personId="+personId ;
        AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getPageFlowScope().put("imageUrl", imageUrl);


       // check  if the image is stored in the file system 
        String fileLocation = "C:\\pics\\" ;

        File imageFile = new File(fileLocation + personId);
        if(imageFile.exists()){
            AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getPageFlowScope().put("personImageExist", true); 
        }else {
    AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getPageFlowScope().put("personImageExist", false); 
        }

        //show the popup here 
        RichPopup.PopupHints hints = new RichPopup.PopupHints();
        this.getImagePopupTab2().show(hints);

    }
}
```

then comes my popup with the af:image  like the following :

```
<af:popup childCreation="immediate" autoCancel="disabled" id="imagePopupTab2"
    binding="#{myBean.imagePopupTab2}" contentDelivery="lazyUncached">
        <af:dialog id="d123456" closeIconVisible="false">
        <af:panelGroupLayout id="pgl899" layout="vertical">
            <af:panelGroupLayout id="pgl1110" layout="horizontal">
            <af:spacer width="20" height="10" id="s34"/>
            <af:image source="#{pageFlowScope.imageUrl}"
                  id="i222" rendered="#{pageFlowScope.personImageExist}"
                 />
            </af:panelGroupLayout>

        </af:panelGroupLayout>
        </af:dialog>
</af:popup>
```

the following works well , **my problem**  comes when i try to update the image file in the file system , then call the popup again , t**he old image is still cached there , and it wont refresh** .

ive tried the following solutions and it didnt work  :

1- add A partial trigger for the **af:image** to refresh after the update.

2- add a partial trigger to **af:image** parent layout to refresh .

3- i tried to set the source attribute to the **af:image** from inside the backing bean .

4- i also tried **h:graphicImage** and **tr:image** same thing .

the problem is , the **af:image** is not calling the source Servlet again , and i dont know why .

Answer (score 1):

Is the servlet URL the same before and after refresh? If so, try adding a param to the URL so that its different after refresh.

For example:

```
/imageservlet?id=302201&refreshTrigger=1
```

It is spoken about briefly in "Important points" of this [blog post](http://davidmasonadf.blogspot.com).

Answer (score 0):

Try to expose af:image's binding into the backing bean:

```
<af:image binding="#{myBean.imageComp" source="#{pageFlowScope.imageUrl}"
                  id="i222" rendered="#{pageFlowScope.personImageExist}"
                 />
```

In myActionListener method, do a programatic PPR:

```
AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addPartialTarget(getImageComp());
```